# Проблема со стилями

Tags: css3, html5

Писал простой блог. Ошибка в том что когда добавляю тег nav и пишу стили для него, то стили применяются и к header. Объясните почему.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Suez+One');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: cursive;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0.5% 10px 0%;
  background-color: #343434;
  float: left;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
}

header #logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
}

header #logo span {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
  color: #fff;
}

header #auth>a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #8c8c8c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b3b3b3;
}

header #auth>a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header #auth>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  line-height: none;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <span>My Blog</span>
  </div>
  <div id="auth">
    <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Contact me</a>
  <a href="#">About me</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте nav `position: relative; display: inline-block;`

Comment: Спасибо. Можете обяснить почему такое происходило?

Comment: Всё просто - блок nav отталкивался от от блока body, при этом отталкивал и блок header. Но задав блоку nav position: relative и display:inline-block, блок nav стал блочно-строчным элементом. Кроме того, начал отталкиваться от родственника - header.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. 
1) Для header в css добавьте overflow: hidden 
2) Между header и nav добавьте постой див и пропишите ему стиль clear: both;

Answer (score 0):

Стили не применяются к header. Припишите для nav clear: both; У вас конфликт полей